# Finding duplicate words in a string python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make my function locate duplicate words and if so the output should be True or False depending on wether there are duplicate words. For example:

```
doubleWord("cat") --> False .      
doubleWord("catcat") --> True .   
doubleWord("contour" * 2) --> True
```

So far I have this:

```
def main():

    word = input("Enter a string: ")

    half = len(word) >> 1
    if word[:half] == word[half:]:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

    return
    print(main())
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I thought maybe using slicing would make it easier but I have no idea how to implement that in my code. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to do? In your example you say that you think `"catcat"` should return `True`. But in your code you're splitting the input where there's a space, so `"catcat"` would be considered a single word.

Comment: @Batman I am trying to make it recognize that there are repeated words/letters.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to compare the first part with the second, you can do this with slicing like this:

```
def doubleWord(word):
    return word[len(word) // 2:] == word[:len(word) // 2]
```

Comment: nice one liner. I would optimize it to return `False` if `len(word)` is odd.

Comment: So it works until the input contour * 2. Any ideas why?